# Can the empty string fields ignored in Kafka coneect sink

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connect to sink data into elastic search. Usually, we ignore the empty fields when persisting to the elastic search. Can we do the same using Kafka connect?

Sample input
`{"field1":"1","field2":""}`

In the elastic index
`{"field1":"1"}`

Comment: I'd suggest modifying your producer code to not send empty strings rather than deal with them afterwards

Answer (score 0):

In kafka connect there is a term called SMT, single message transformation,  it has several types of supported functions,  but none of them doing what you wish for, you can however write your on SMT doing that action ,

● Create your JAR file.

● Install the JAR file. Copy your custom SMT JAR file (and any non-Kafka JAR files required by the transformation) into a directory that is under one of the directories listed in the `plugin.path` property in the Connect worker configuration

refer to further instructions

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html